# Magento 2.2.5 new customer account form not working for Chrome, Internet Explorer but works fine in Mozilla

Tags: magento2, customer-account, xampp, chrome-browser, magento-2.2.5

New customer account form not working for Chrome and Internet Explorer but works fine in Mozilla. Both updated version of Magento and Fresh Installation of Magento 2.2.5, both are not working.

Magento version - 2.2.5 (Fresh Install)

XAMPP Version: 7.1.19

Comment: Try to replace Localhost  as `127.0.0.1` OR You can create Virtual Host for this.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer.

Step 1: ( `<?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>` )Add this code inside the "register.phtml" after `<form>`.

Step 2: Change your link http://localhst/magento into http://127.0.0.1/magento

step 3: Clear the cache using `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Answer (score 0):

You can do either of the 2 things mentioned below:

- Navigate to **Stores > Configuration > Admin > Security > Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout** and disable this option.

  ```
                       **OR**
  ```
- Go to **database > core_config_data (table)** replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 something like **http://localhost/xyz** to **http://127.0.0.1/xyz/** where path is **web/secure/base_url** & **web/unsecure/base_url**

Feel free to ping if you face any problem.